# How would I implement a splash screen that animates away?

Tags: objective-c, animation, storyboard, splash-screen

This is what I have so far:

```
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize tabBarController = _tabBarController;

-(void)animate
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        splashImage.frame = CGRectMake(0,480,320,480);
    }];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    splashImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage
                                                      imageNamed:@"carolinaWolf.png"]];
    splashImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:splashImage];
    [self animate];
    return YES;
}
```

My initial view in storyboard is a TabBarController. What I want to happen is: after I finish loading new content into the application, I want to splash screen to animate down and off the screen. This worked before I started using storyboard, why won't it work now?

My AppDelegate.h looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
@end
UIImageView *splashImage;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly just add your `splashImage` to `self.window.rootViewController` like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIImage *splashImage = [UIImage autoAdjustImageNamed:@"Default.png"];
    UIImageView *splashImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:splashImage];
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:splashImageView];
    [self.window.rootViewController.view bringSubviewToFront:splashImageView];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5f
                          delay:2.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         splashImageView.alpha = .0f;
                         CGFloat x = -60.0f;
                         CGFloat y = -120.0f;
                         splashImageView.frame = CGRectMake(x,
                                                            y,
                                                            splashImageView.frame.size.width-2*x,
                                                            splashImageView.frame.size.height-2*y);
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         if (finished) {
                             [splashImageView removeFromSuperview];
                         }
                     }];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This is similar to what I use, but I'm facing problems with iPad being at different orientations - any tips?

Comment: @OdedBenDov What is your problem? Maybe you should ask your own question instead of add comment here.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fade away my splash screens:

### #pragma mark Fading Default.png Animation

```
@interface FadeDefault : UIViewController
@end
@implementation FadeDefault

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImageView *fader = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default@2x.png"]];
    [fader setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];

    /*if ( IDIOM == IPAD ) /* Optional */
    {
        fader = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Portrait~ipad.png"]];  
        [fader setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,768,1024)];
    }else
      {
        fader = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default@2x.png"]];
        [fader setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
    }*/
    self.view = fader;
    [fader release];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(imageDidFadeOut:finished:context:)];
    self.view.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
- (void)imageDidFadeOut:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context{
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
@end
```

### #pragma mark - Application lifecycle

Keep in mind this is an example, although code I actually use and I know works, you need to keep your other `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` code in place. Just add the `fader` code to you existing code.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    /*  custom fading Default.png animation  */
    FadeDefault * fader = [[FadeDefault alloc] init];

    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];

    [window addSubview:fader.view];
    [fader release];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```